# vDSP fft computation good practice

Tags: macos, fft, accelerate-framework, vdsp

In order to compute the FFT with Accelerate framework, I see a lot of people using (the old way I guess) `fft_zrip` instead of the recommended one by Apple in the vDSP documentation `​DSP_DFT_Execute`.

Is there any reason why `​DSP_DFT_Execute` is so under used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DFT API is newer, so it is not as well known. The FFT API was around for many years, so knowledge of it has spread, along with examples around the net.

For lengths that are powers of two, they will use the same implementation underneath the API.

Answer (score 1):

Actually for real-to-complex FFT both `vDSP_fft_zrip` and `DSP_DFT_Execute`  [require data in split even-odd format](https://developer.apple.com/reference/accelerate/1450538-vdsp_dft_execute#discussion).

Comment: Indeed... Sorry I've little issue in the understanding of the documentation. I will edit my question.